# Part time MPH degree while doing full time PhD

Tags: phd, graduate-school

I will be joining a full-time PhD program in North America in August (physical and biological sciences). While my PhD topic is my principal interest, I'm also interested in public health and health policy related challenges, and this will help me in my planned future career. I have observed that there are a number of online (part-time) MSc / MPH degrees in public health being offered by well-respected universities.

My question is:

a) Is it generally speaking permissible to enrol in another part-time program while you are pursuing a full time PhD?

b) Based on my own previous research experience, chat with my future supervisor and the members of the research group, my schedule is likely to be anywhere between 7-9 hours a day (weekends free). In principle, 20 hours of work (per week) on a part-time degree is something I should be able to do, however is this practical?

If it helps, PhD will be in experimental science (laboratory work)

Look forward to perspectives

Comment: "practical"? - enjoyable/rewarding/meaningful...you wanna look for a job with your MPH or PhD degree after everything finished, this would be my question. Some ppl only work and like a robot (and still don't get tenure) and some have a life... technically the biggest problem I see is doing your master thesis work over months during 7-9 hours for your PhD, hard to shift to the weekend...

Comment: Any chance your school offers such a dual-degree program? Mine does, though you have to apply for it specifically. It would be unusual but probably not impossible to add the masters after you've already been accepted for PhD (and with the blessing of an advisor).

Comment: Unfortunately, the school does not offer such a dual degree program. Even if it did, I would much rather go for a flexible, part-time, online program than an offline one with real lectures to attend. Some of the online programs can be completed in even 3-4 years.